# python extract number from a text file and storage them in a list of lists

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file. I only want to storage the numbers from the text. For example: This is the text in the file

ihlisdf 0.11 husj 0.2 khlkhhb,mbx blabla 2.2 fjd 3.3 0.5 jdkjkd 4.4

I need the script to save only the numbers in a list of list like this

[[0.11,0.2,2.2],[3.3,0.5,4.4]]

I tried the following

```
postemp=open('positionfile.txt','r')

str=postemp.read()
postemp.close()
c=re.findall('\d+.\d+', str)

i=0
new_list=[]
while i<len(c):
  new_list.append(c[i:i+3])
  i+=3
```

But it storage the numbers as a string. I need the numbers like float digits because I have to do some calculus with them

Comment: Try using `new_list.append(list(map(int, c[i:i+3])))` instead to convert the string array to an int array.

Comment: but I dont want an int array, I want a float array

Comment: Replace `int`, with `float`: i.e. `new_list.append(list(map(float, c[i:i+3])))`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

Let me know if you want me to explain anything

```
import numpy as np
import re
with open('positionfile.txt') as  f:
    str = f.read()
    s = re.findall('\d+\.?\d+?', str)
    # the below converts the 1 dimensional vexotr into a 2 dimensional matrix with width 3
    list = np.array(s).reshape(len(s)/3, 3).astype(float)


print list
```

The output:

```
[[ 0.1  0.2  2.2]
 [ 3.3  0.5  4.4]]
```

Comment: It gives me the same result as my code. I need the elements of the list to be numbers, not charaters.

Comment: @LisLou Update - (just added `.astype(float)` to make the elements floats)... I would really suggest looking into Numpy - it's amazing :)

Comment: the problem is when I extract the numbers from the the text file. I need them to be storaged as numbers and not  charater strings

Comment: Are you using the updated code - (note the end part on second last line)?

Comment: `.astype(float)` should convert each element in the vector from a character string to a number (i.e. float)

Comment: okay the .astype(float) worked but I noticed another problem. re.findall('\d+.?\d+?', str) is not extracting well the numbers... it storages 0.1 2,3 4.4 as 0.1 23 4.4

Comment: Good catch - This is because in regular expressions, the `.` matches any character. Thus, I escape the `.` (i.e. added a '\' before the dot) to ensure it only matches a literal `.` and not any other character...

Answer (score 0):

```
text = 'ihlisdf 0.11 husj 0.2 khlkhhb,mbx blabla 2.2 fjd 3.3 0.5 jdkjkd 4.4'
all_num = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', text)
for i in range(0, len(all_num), 3):
    m = all_num[i:i+3]
    m = [float(j)for j in m]
    print(m)
```

out:

```
[0.11, 0.2, 2.2]
[3.3, 0.5, 4.4]
```